# Trying to loop through text files in a directory, open each, search contents, and print if a match is found

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code must be close, but something is off here.  I am trying to loop through text files in a directory, open each, search contents, and print if a match is found in the string.

```
import os

search_path = 'C:\\my_path\\'
file_type = '.txt'
search_str = '941,266,881'

z = 0
#search_str = str(search_str)
my_list = search_str.split(",")
#print(my_list)
for item in my_list:
    z += 1
    print(z)

    # Append a directory separator if not already present
    if not (search_path.endswith("/") or search_path.endswith("\\")):
        search_path = search_path + "/"

    # If path does not exist, set search path to current directory
    if not os.path.exists(search_path):
        search_path = "."

    # Repeat for each file in the directory
    for fname in os.listdir(path=search_path):

        # Apply file type filter
        if fname.endswith(file_type):

            # Open file for reading
            fo = open(search_path + fname)

            # Read the first line from the file
            line = fo.readline()

            # Initialize counter for line number
            line_no = 1

            # Loop until EOF
            while line != '':
                # Search for string in line
                index = line.find(item)
                if (index != -1):
                    print(fname, "[", line_no, ",", index, "] ", line, sep="")

                # Read next line
                line = fo.readline()

                # Increment line counter
                line_no += 1

            # Close the files
            fo.close()
```

Comment: Did you print `my_list` to see what it is?

Comment: Why all the *search\_str* fiasco? Why not simply `my_list = ['941', '266', '881']`?

Comment: please attach the full stacktrace of `TypeError: must be str, not list`. It's not clear where the error comes from

Comment: The error occurs on this line: index = line.find(my_list)

Answer (score 0):

Your search_str is already a list.  You don't need to convert it to a string and then split it to a list.  When you do that, the three elements of my_list become "['941'", " '266'" and " '881']"

Comment: I thought so too.  But when I tried that, I get this: TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: print `my_list` and see its contents

Comment: print(my_list)
["['941'", " '266'", " '881']"]

Comment: Oh, I see what the issue was.  It should be setup like this:
search_str = '941,266,881'

Comment: Just updated my original post with the full working code.  Now it's a solution and not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the code which will show what's in `my_list`.
That's not what you want, probably

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 10 2019, 11:58:48) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> search_str = ['941','266','881']
>>> search_str = str(search_str)
>>> my_list = search_str.split(",")
>>> my_list
["['941'", " '266'", " '881']"]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks rok.  I just tried that.  I'm getting the same thing.  

TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: The code i shared is not meant to solve the error, but to show you  `my_list` contains probably something wrong. If you understand that and how to solve it (see post comments), you may understand why `TypeError: must be str, not list` error happens